# How to use Composer's autoloader to autoload arbitrary classes/namespaces not configured in composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

For reasons that are unimportant (let's just call it an intellectual curiosity) I'm trying to use Composer's autoloader to load a package not in `composer.json`/`composer.lock`.

Here's what I've tried:

```php
$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();
$loader->addPsr4('MyNameSpace\\', __DIR__ . '/vendor/username/projectname/src');
$loader->register();
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. Whenever I try to do `use MyNameSpace\Whatever; $a = new Whatever;` I get an error about how `Whatever` can't be found.

Comment: Why not add such details to the autoloader section of your `composer.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this file structure:

[image]

Where class `Test1` is:

```php
// out/Test1.php
class Test1
{
    public function foo(): string 
    {
        return "foo bar baz";
    }
}
```

and class `FooBar/Console/Test2` is:

```
// psr4/someroot/Console/Test2
namespace FooBar\Console;

class Test2
{
    public function bar(): string
    {
        return "fizz buzz";
    }
}
```

and having this on the test script (`test.php`)

```
// test.php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader();

$loader->add('Test1', __DIR__ . '/out');
$loader->addPsr4('FooBar\\', __DIR__ . '/psr4/someroot');

$loader->register();

$t1 = new Test1();
$t2 = new \FooBar\Console\Test2();

echo $t1->foo(), "\n";
echo $t2->bar(), "\n";
```

I can run `php test.php` perfectly fine.

So something else must be misconfigured in your project. Use the above example as a guide to fix it.